# Regex to limit comma separated strings to 10

Tags: regex

Using regex, I need to limit the string on a comma separated string.

I came up with this regex: `^([^,]*,[^,]*){0,9}$`

Now it is working for `1,2` but also for `1,2,` which is not valid. Also, it don't accept `1` or `*`, it always requires me a single `,`.

Comment: Try `^(?=.{0,9}$)[^,]+(?:,[^,]+)*$`

Comment: Try this https://regex101.com/r/yfLBgg/3

Comment: You can use: `^[^,]+(?:,[^,]+){0,9}$`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - i think the length of the entire string was limited to 9

Comment: It worked @anubhava. Thanks guys!

Comment: @SahilGulati - it should also work for single character without comma as stated in the question. Thanks btw!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this regex for your job to allow 1 to 10 comma delimited strings:

```
^[^,]+(?:,[^,]+){0,9}$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wlharo/1)

**RegEx Breakup:**

- `^`: Start
- `[^,]+`: Match 1 more non-comma characters
- `(?:`: Start non-capturing group

  - `,`: Match literal comma
  - `[^,]+`: Match 1 more non-comma characters
- `)`: End non-capturing group
- `{0,9}`: Match 0 to 9 of what we matched inside the group
- `$`: End

Comment: Can you add an explanation to your answer? I wanted to understand it deeper.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: @anubhava how do modify the regex so each word is exactly 10 characters long?

Comment: @UmairAyub: Just replace `[^,]+` with `[^,]{10}` in both places.